# Problems with legends for list density plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics3d, legending

When plotting list density plot in *Mathematica* 8.0, the following problems arise:

1. `PlotLegends` doesn't work, so I use `ShowLegend` which withdraws the second problem:
2. the difficulties in matching the density colors with corresponding label colors in legend, i.e. it does not display automatically. Also legend does not display max and min density values, nor the intermediate ticks.

Here I outline my code:

```
d = ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["FallColors"], ClippingStyle -> Automatic];

max_d = Max[data[[All,3]]];
min_d = Min[data[[All,3]]];

ShowLegend[d, {ColorData["FallColors"][1 - #] &, 10, "max_d", "min_d", 
  LegendShadow -> None, LegendPosition -> {1.5, -0.7} }]
```

where data is a table containing elements of the form $\{x_i, y_i ,f(x_i, y_i)\}$, in particular

```
data = {
  {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, 
  {1, 0, Cos[1]}, {1, 1, Cos[1]^2}, {1, 2, Cos[1] Cos[2]}, {1, 3, Cos[1] Cos[3]}, 
  {1, 4, Cos[1] Cos[4]}, {2, 0, Cos[2]}, {2, 1, Cos[2]^2}, {2, 2, Cos[2] Cos[4]}, 
  {2, 3, Cos[2] Cos[6]}, {2, 4, Cos[2] Cos[8]}, {3, 0, Cos[3]}, {3, 1, Cos[3]^2}, 
  {3, 2, Cos[3] Cos[6]}, {3, 3, Cos[3] Cos[9]}, {3, 4, Cos[3] Cos[12]}
}
```

However, I would like to have more gradual display (not only 10 different shades) in legend, and automatic evaluation of min and max.

Comment: Your question will get more attention if you provide a sample dataset for `data` in your post.  Also, note that `PlotLegends` was introduced in version 9.0 so is not available in 8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(*  "8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 22, 2012)"  *)

data = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, {1, 0, 
    Cos[1]}, {1, 1, Cos[1]^2}, {1, 2, Cos[1] Cos[2]}, {1, 3, 
    Cos[1] Cos[3]}, {1, 4, Cos[1] Cos[4]}, {2, 0, Cos[2]}, {2, 1, 
    Cos[2]^2}, {2, 2, Cos[2] Cos[4]}, {2, 3, Cos[2] Cos[6]}, {2, 4, 
    Cos[2] Cos[8]}, {3, 0, Cos[3]}, {3, 1, Cos[3]^2}, {3, 2, 
    Cos[3] Cos[6]}, {3, 3, Cos[3] Cos[9]}, {3, 4, Cos[3] Cos[12]}};

d = ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["FallColors"], ClippingStyle -> Automatic];
```

Note that you cannot use an underscore in a variable name

```
maxD = Max[data[[All, 3]]];
minD = Min[data[[All, 3]]];

Needs["PlotLegends`"]

ShowLegend[d, {
  ColorData["FallColors"][1 - #] &,
  25, ToString[maxD], ToString[minD],
  LegendShadow -> None,
  LegendSize -> {.4, 1.5},
  LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.7}}]
```

[image]